# Elasticsearch - how to get a list of hits with specific field

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following docs on the ES:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "test1"}
{"id": 2, "name": "test2"}
{"id": 3, "name": "test3"}
{"id": 4, "name": "test4"}
```

and following is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "test"
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "id"
  ]
}
```

I want to get just a list of ids instead of getting whole data from ES. My desired output will be `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.
I want to use something like `Model.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)` of Django.
Is it possible to get data as I want in elasticseach?

Answer (score 0):

You should use either of

```
"fields": ["id"], "_source": false
```

(this would only work for indexed fields)

or

```
"_source": ["id"]
```

this will work for any field but will be a bit slower